# Anylogic Distribution Network connection from database

Tags: java, anylogic

I have a specific question regarding an Anylogic model that I am trying to build.

I have 3 tables:

1. connections with columns *connecteddc* and *connectedcustomer*
2. customer with columns *custname* and *demand*
3. dcdetails with columns *dcname* and *dccapactiy*

I am trying to write a java code that connects each dc in the first table (*connecteddc*) to each customer assigned (*connectedcustomer*) and iterates through this process multiple times to build an accurate network. I have tried using several variations of code, as shown below.

```
for (int i=0; i<3 ; i++){
        dc.get(i).LinktoCustomers.connectTo(Locations.get(selectFirstValue(false, int.class, "SELECT connectedcustomer FROM connections WHERE connectedDC = "+i+";")));
}
```

This code is only connecting 1 DC to 1 customer. This problem is occurring in the 'selectFirstValue' portion of the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Database Query**

You have to use one of the possibilies to retrieve all of the concerning database entries, instead of just the first one, as you do with `selectFirstValue()`. Here is one option to do so:

```
for (int i=0; i<dc.size() ; i++){
    List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(connection)
        .where(connection.connecteddc.eq(dc.get(i).dcName))
        .list();

    for (Tuple row : rows) {
        dc.get(i).connectTo(getCustomerByName(row.get(connection.connectedcustomer)));
    }
}
```

Tipp: AnyLogic offers you an assistant to create such queries, that you find in the AnyLogic toolbar under "Insert Database Query". It looks like this:
[AnyLogic Database Query Assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0ScK.png)

**Other Stuff**

I modified a couple of other things that catched my attention:

- To add a connection you use `dc.get(i).LinktoCustomers.connectTo(...)`. It is not neccessary to use a special variable for the connections, it is enough to just add it to the standard connections by using: `dc.get(i).connectTo(...)`
- You go through the list of DCs with a hardcoded max index. As soon as you change the number of entries in the DC table, the code will not work anymore. I recommend something like this: `for (int i=0; i<dc.size() ; i++){...}`.
- You gave the name "Locations" to your population of Agent type "Customer". It is confusing to use a population name that doesn't reflect the underlying agent type at all. I recommend to rename it for example "Customers".
- To access your DCs you store and use the index number of the DC as an integer in the tables. In order to be on the safe side, I recommend to use unique String Ids instead, which will work even if you change to order of your table. For this to work you'll need to "parse" the Id (stored in the tables) to a Customer object.

This could be done in a function `getCustomerByName(String name)` like this (although this obviously lacks error handling):

```
for(Customer c:Customers){
    if(c.custName.equals(name)){
        return c;
    }
}
return null;
```